# How do I make markdown or org mode hide formatting characters until I edit?

Tags: org-mode, markdown-mode

I'd like to hide markdown / org-mode markup characters when viewing a file, so I set `org-hide-emphasis-markers` and `markdown-hide-markup` to `t`. However, when *editing* a section of text, I'd like to see the characters. A function like `markdown-toggle-markup-hiding` will change the setting for the entire buffer.

Is there an easy way to apply the hiding to the entire buffer *except* the current line (or paragraph)? That way most of the buffer will be in "view" mode but when I move the cursor to edit something, that line will let me see the formatting characters.

Comment: That sounds expensive to me: emacs would have to recalculate every time you move and although that's possible, it needs care lest it slow down everything to a crawl - maybe it can be done with an idle timer.

Answer (score 5):

I have a quick & dirty proof of concept for markdown-mode. Idea: keep track of the current line (similar to hl-line-mode). Use a font-lock rule to remove the markup hiding for the current line (markdown-mode seems to use `display` and `invisible` text properties, so remove those). Re-fontify the local area when moving from one line to another.

```
(defvar my/current-line '(0 . 0)
  "(start . end) of current line in current buffer")
(make-variable-buffer-local 'my/current-line)

(defun my/unhide-current-line (limit)
  "Font-lock function"
  (let ((start (max (point) (car my/current-line)))
        (end (min limit (cdr my/current-line))))
    (when (< start end)
      (remove-text-properties start end 
                      '(invisible t display "" composition ""))
      (goto-char limit)
      t)))

(defun my/refontify-on-linemove ()
  "Post-command-hook"
  (let* ((start (line-beginning-position))
         (end (line-beginning-position 2))
         (needs-update (not (equal start (car my/current-line)))))
    (setq my/current-line (cons start end))
    (when needs-update
      (font-lock-fontify-block 3))))

(defun my/markdown-unhighlight ()
  "Install"
  (markdown-toggle-markup-hiding 1)
  (font-lock-add-keywords nil '((my/unhide-current-line)) t)
  (add-hook 'post-command-hook #'my/refontify-on-linemove nil t))

(add-hook 'markdown-mode-hook #'my/markdown-unhighlight)
```

I don't know if this is the best way to do it. I'm seeing some occasional errors in the message area but it seems to be working ok so far.

Edit: also works in org mode with `(add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'my/markdown-unhighlight)`

Comment: This can also be used with org mode. Remove the `composition` text property to undo org-pretty-entities on the current line.