# Disable 'beautification' of text when point is on same line in org

Tags: org-mode, org-link, gui-emacs, prettify-symbols-mode

When writing `org` documents, some parts of the text (like links and figures) automatically get 'beautified' (I'm unsure what the technically correct term is), meaning that some surrounding text elements (e.g. the brackets) gets hidden automatically.

Although that looks nice, it's sometimes inconvenient for me, especially if I want to change some parts of it.
Therefore I'm looking for an option to disable the 'beautification' when the point is on the same line.

Any ideas on how I could do that?
I'm currently using `Emacs 26.1` on `Debian stable (Buster)` (actually `PureOS 9.0 Amber`).

---

ps.: To me this seems similar to the `prettify-symbols-mode` but from what I understand it must be a different function that is handling this.

Answer (score 4):

I've wanted this too.

1. (2021) Try the [org-appear](https://github.com/awth13/org-appear) package, which can toggle emphasis, entities, and a few other things while your cursor is in the hidden text (not the entire line though). There are settings to choose which of these categories to display.
2. (2019) Try [my experimental code](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/47632/how-do-i-make-markdown-or-org-mode-hide-formatting-characters-until-i-edit), which shows all the hidden characters on the current line. It works in both org and markdown mode, but it has some glitches at times.